# Flutter add a black outline to top of BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter

I am trying to figure out how to add a very subtle black line to the top of a BottomNavigationBar to make it's start more distinct from the rest of the content. AirBnb would be a good example of this.

Is there a way to achieve this with Flutter?

Below is the widget I am currently using to render the BottomNavigationBar and I have attached a sample below where there is a distinct grey line at the top of the navbar for AirBnb.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: currentPage,
    bottomNavigationBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
      child: Container (
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
        ),
      )
    ),
  );
}
```

The parent of this Widget:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: new MyApp(),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navbar();
  }
}
```

[image: Sample image from the AirBnb app]

Comment: post a sample of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Doc I have added an image for reference

Comment: You need to add some code which have you tried so far.

Answer (score 24):

**How to add line on top of bottom navigation view in flutter ?**

**Code**

```
class BottomNavigationBarHandler {
  Widget bar(int currentIndex) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3.0))),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
            showSelectedLabels: false,
            showUnselectedLabels: false,
            onTap: onTabTapped,
            currentIndex: currentIndex,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
                title: Text('Home')),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                title: Text('Messages')),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add), 
                title: Text('Profile'))]));
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
     print('BottomNavigationBarIndex ::' + index.toString());
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Best easiest answer, Perfect!

Answer (score 14):

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(200),
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: globals.white,
          height: 100,
          child: Text('imyadunandan'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: globals.white,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: globals.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: globals.black,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.android),
              title: Text('Android'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.desktop_windows),
              title: Text('Windows'),
            ),
          ],
          backgroundColor: globals.white,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

this code achieves the fallowing

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really seem to get this to work :( When I try doing something like this my screen just renders all white

Comment: Show what you're trying to do

Comment: I have attached the current code I am using to render the BottomNavigationBar as well as a picture as a sample

Comment: check the answer

Comment: When I set the PreferredSize code to the bottomNavigationBar component of the scaffold it renders an all white screen. I am going to update the code in my question.

Comment: What's the parent of scaffold? MaterialApp?

Comment: I have added the parent to the question

Comment: ```BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey[400], offset: Offset(0, -0.5))``` This way it removes the bottom line that also creates.